# Prove the tower property for conditional expectation using filters

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, conditional-expectation

While studying about martingales I came about the following proposition : 
*$$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F}_n)|\mathcal{F}_m) = \mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F}_m)$$ if $m \le n$ where $\mathcal{F}_n$ is the filter defined on $X_0,...,X_n$*
Is it possible to prove the same **without** using the field, measurability and indicator function arguments as given here : [Steve Cheng's Notes](http://www.gold-saucer.org/math/conditional/conditional.pdf) ? 
Note : I think $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F}_t)$ can be taken to be equal to $\mathbb{E}(X | X_0,X_1,X_2,.....,X_t)$ in a *field-less world*

Comment: How is $E(X\mid Y)$ any less field-worldy than $E(X\mid\mathcal G)$?

Comment: @Did I don't know, what I inferred was to seek an answer without evoking the notion of sigma-fields.Sorry if it hurt your eyes.

Comment: My eyes are all right, thanks, the trouble I have is to understand what a question akin to "show that there are infinitely many primes, but *without evoking the notion of* divisibility" could mean.

Answer (score 1):

The first equation is an application of the tower property. If $\mathcal H$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{G}$, then $E[X | \mathcal{H}] = E[E[X|\mathcal {G}] \mathcal{H}]$. There is no need for a filtration to use this property, but there is a need for $\sigma$-algebras.

As for your second question, the answer is a bit subtle. If you are talking about martingales, there **must** be a filtration. This is not inconsistent with taking $E[X|X_0,\ldots,X_n]$ though, because by definition $E[Z|X_0,\ldots,X_n] = E[Z| \sigma(X_0,\ldots,X_n)] = E[Z|\mathcal{F}^X_n]$. That is, if $X$ is a process, one can always consider the filtration generated by $X$, defined by $\mathcal{F}^X_n := \sigma(X_0,\ldots,X_n)$. In many situations this is the most natural choice, and some authors will talk about $X$ "being a martingale" without referring to a filtration. In these cases they always mean $X$ is a martingale relative to the filtration $\mathcal{F}^X$.

Comment: Thanks,but can you pls elaborate on the first para of your answer and possibly tha proof as well,Also shouldn't it be H is a sub algebra of G,to conform with the original question  ?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with specifically?

Comment: The part :   E [E [X|G]|H] = E [X|H] where H is a sub algebra of G

Comment: By the definition of what conditional expectation is, it suffices to check that for any $H \in \mathcal{H}$ we have $E[ 1_H E[X | \mathcal{H}]] =  E[1_H E[E[X|\mathcal{G}]|\mathcal{H}]]$. But any $H \in \mathcal{H}$ is also in $\mathcal{G}$ and hence $$E[1_H E[E[X|\mathcal{G}]|\mathcal{H}]] = E[1_H E[X|\mathcal{G}]] = E[1_H X] = E[1_H E[X|\mathcal{H}]].$$